# Java JVM terminate in Aptana and Ecplise

Tags: java, linux, jvm, out-of-memory

I want to use AptanaStudio,Eclipse and after running that i get this error.

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=1
/usr/bin/java
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-Declipse.p2.unsignedPolicy=allow
-Declipse.log.size.max=10000
-Declipse.log.backup.max=5
-Djava.awt.headless=true
-jar /home/tux-world/Desktop/Home/packages/Aptana_Studio_3//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86
-showsplash
-launcher /home/tux-world/Desktop/Home/packages/Aptana_Studio_3/AptanaStudio3
-name Aptana Studio 3
--launcher.library /home/tux-world/Desktop/Home/packages/Aptana_Studio_3//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.1.100.v20110505/eclipse_1407.so
-startup /home/tux-world/Desktop/Home/packages/Aptana_Studio_3//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.overrideVmargs
-exitdata 6e8011
-vm /usr/bin/java
-vmargs
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-Declipse.p2.unsignedPolicy=allow
-Declipse.log.size.max=10000
-Declipse.log.backup.max=5
-Djava.awt.headless=true
-jar /home/tux-world/Desktop/Home/packages/Aptana_Studio_3//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
```

this commands do not resolve my problem

```
export JVM_ARGS="-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its due to out of memory, try to increase the heap memory as below

```
-Xms512m
-Xmx1g
```

You may need to change in the eclipse.ini file.